# Wrapper to save methods results

Tags: javascript

Im trying to write a Wrapper for an chained method:

```
new Example().child("First").child("Second").read(function(name){console.log(name)})
```

**The wrapper should save the result of the first execution.** The next time the wrapper gets called with the same method it should not execute the original method, **it should return the saved result**:

```
wrapper = new Wrapper();
//this time the result of the passed method gets saved
wrapper.wrap(new Example().child("First").child("Second").read, function(name){console.log(name)})
//now it should return the saved value
wrapper.wrap(new Example().child("First").child("Second").read, function(name){console.log(name)})
```

I want to implement this feature for calls to a database lib. When the device has no internet connection it should read from the saved wrapper states.

I implemented the wrapper like this:

```
Wrapper = function () {
    this.saved_funcs = {}
}

Wrapper.prototype.wrap = function (func, callbac) {
    if (func in this.saved_funcs) {
        callbac(this.saved_funcs[func]);
    } else {
        func(function (result) {
            this.saved_funcs[func] = result;
            callbac(result);
        }.bind(this))
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/boaLf6s3/1/

But when I execute the wrapper it returns undefined? My example would always store the whole code to check if the method was already triggerd. **Thats why I would like to ask you how you would implement such a wrapper?** Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are trying to reference needs to be executed from the object's context because it uses `this`. Is better if you just pass the object and call `read` instead:

```js
Example = function(){
 this.text = "";
}

Example.prototype.child = function(name){
 this.text += name + " " + name;
 return this;
}

Example.prototype.read = function(callbac){
 callbac(this.text);
}



Wrapper = function(){
 this.saved_funcs = {}
}


Wrapper.prototype.wrap = function(obj, callbac){
 if(obj.read in this.saved_funcs){
  callbac(this.saved_funcs[obj.read]);
 }else{
  obj.read(function(result){
   this.saved_funcs[obj.read] = result;
   callbac(result);
  }.bind(this))
 }
};



new Example().child("First").child("Second").read(function(name){document.getElementById("normal").innerHTML = name})


wrapper = new Wrapper();

wrapper.wrap(new Example().child("First").child("Second"), function(name){console.log(name)})

wrapper.wrap(new Example().child("First").child("Second"), function(name){ document.getElementById("saved").innerHTML = name })
```

```html
<h2>
  Normal Result
</h2>
<p id="normal">
  
</p>
<h2>
  Saved Result
</h2>
<p id="saved">
  
</p>
```

Or you could bind your function like this:

```js
Example = function(){
 this.text = "";
}

Example.prototype.child = function(name){
 this.text += name + " " + name;
 return this;
}

Example.prototype.read = function(callbac){
 callbac(this.text);
}



Wrapper = function(){
 this.saved_funcs = {}
}


Wrapper.prototype.wrap = function(func, callbac){
 if(func in this.saved_funcs){
  callbac(this.saved_funcs[func]);
 }else{
  func(function(result){
   this.saved_funcs[func] = result;
   callbac(result);
  }.bind(this))
 }
};



new Example().child("First").child("Second").read(function(name){document.getElementById("normal").innerHTML = name})


wrapper = new Wrapper();

var child = new Example().child('First').child('Second');
var read = child.read.bind(child);

wrapper.wrap(read, function(name){console.log(name)})

wrapper.wrap(read, function(name){ document.getElementById("saved").innerHTML = name })
```

```html
<h2>
  Normal Result
</h2>
<p id="normal">
  
</p>
<h2>
  Saved Result
</h2>
<p id="saved">
  
</p>
```